# (404 Not Found) angular2-datatable

Tags: angular, typescript, datatable

I searched so many answers want to fix this problem, but still not works:

My console output show that can't find angular2-datatalbe：

> 404 GET /angular2-datatable

And my systemjs.config:

--

```
map: {
  'lodash': 'npm:lodash/lodash.js',
  'angular2-datatable':'npm:angular2-datatable'
},
packages: {
  app: {
    main: './main.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  rxjs: {
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  }, 'lodash': {
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  'angular2-datatable': {
    main: './index.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  }
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code block:

From:

```
'angular2-datatable': {
    main: './index.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
}
```

To:

```
'angular2-datatable': {
    main: 'index.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
}
```

Comment: Yes , I closed my Visual Studio Code and restart it , but the same problem  appear .

Comment: will you please remove , 'lodash': {
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  }, and try again ?

Comment: It is still have the problem

Comment: have any live url or plunker for this ?

Comment: I don't have any plunker or url for this , sorry .

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
  map: {
 'lodash': 'npm:lodash/lodash.js',
     'angular2-datatable': 'npm:angular2-datatable/index.js',
    },
```

Also

```
'angular2-datatable': {

    defaultExtension: 'js'
}
```